# When app deployed with Java Web start, App is full screen ( not desired )

Tags: java

I recently deployed my app with JWS, the result is that the app occupies far more height than the desktop screen. result of which i cannot see the title & the menu bar and other buttons of the frame. I want to set the screen size to a smaller size , how to do it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: BTW - my best guess is that this has **nothing** to do with Java Web Start.  What is the size of the frame when run as a plain Jar, as opposed to launched by JWS (and I want pixel values for those answers)?

Comment: the pixel value of screen is 1280*800.

Comment: I did not ask for the size of the screen, I asked for the size of the **FRAMES!**  Please read comments & answers carefully.  Ask if there is something you do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

Call [Window.setSize(Dimension)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29) or it's overloaded variant.  Next time you might try Reading The Fine Manual, which is quicker than the (checks) 50+ minutes you spent waiting for these pearls of wisdom.